# Copy Google presentation to a folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, copy

I would like to make a copy of a slideshow, and put that copy into a specific folder. I'm having trouble with the commands for getting and copying the slideshow file.

```
  //presentation destination
  var slideDestination = DriveApp.getFolderById(ID HERE);

  //get the template
  var slideTemplate = "URL ADDRESS"

  //make the copy           
  var newSlide = DriveApp.getFileById(slideTemplate).makeCopy('NAME', slideDestination);
```

Seems like a simple enough idea--get the file, get the destination, make the copy. But for some reason I'm getting an error, saying the ID for slideTemplate can't be found. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideTemplate` should not be the URL of the slide it is a [portion of it](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/overview#the_structure_of_a_presentation).

> https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/***SlideID***/edit

Copy that piece of the URL and assign it to `slideTemplate = "SlideID"`.